# RPC:S-5:AEC-0 keep on getting it,after doing everything thats advise to do

Tags: android

Got a senua tablet and keep getting error message RPC:S-5:AEC-0. Have been doing what has been advised, it works for 1 download and then it gives me that message again. Can anybody help????